# Using boost::visitor with a boost::variant of unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, unique-ptr, boost-variant

I have two types of std::unique_ptr which are held inside a boost::variant. I'm trying to write a subclass of boost::static_visitor to extract a const reference to to the underlying object the two unique_ptr variants my boost::variant is templated on. The setup looks something like this:

```
using bitmap_flyweight_t = boost::flyweights::flyweight<allegro_bitmap_t>;
using image_bitmap_flyweight_t = boost::flyweights::flyweight<boost::flyweights::key_value<const char*, allegro_bitmap_t>>;

class bitmap_visitor : public boost::static_visitor<allegro_bitmap_t>
{
public:
    const allegro_bitmap_t& operator()(const std::unique_ptr<bitmap_flyweight_t> bitmap_ptr) const
    {
        return bitmap_ptr.get()->get();
    }

    const allegro_bitmap_t& operator()(const std::unique_ptr<image_bitmap_flyweight_t> bitmap_ptr) const
    {
        return bitmap_ptr.get()->get();
    }
};
```

I'm able to put the unique_ptrs into an object's boost::variant member variable on instantiation using move semantics, no compiler complaints there. However, when I try to access the variant type using the above visitor, the compiler complains that it can't do it, as unique_ptr is not copy constructible.

Comment: Have you tried accepting a reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accept a const reference to the unique pointer.

```
class bitmap_visitor : public boost::static_visitor<allegro_bitmap_t>
{
public:
    const allegro_bitmap_t& operator()(const std::unique_ptr<bitmap_flyweight_t>& bitmap_ptr) const
    {
        return bitmap_ptr.get()->get();
    }

    const allegro_bitmap_t& operator()(const std::unique_ptr<image_bitmap_flyweight_t>& bitmap_ptr) const
    {
        return bitmap_ptr.get()->get();
    }
};
```

Here's a [live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/7K9umo7k0lCOzj5J) of a toy project.

Comment: Ah, sure. I'm somewhat new to using smart pointers in my projects, so I think the notion of passing a "reference to a pointer" was tripping me up...

Comment: @Bitrex just think of them as of regular objects. You can't copy a noncopyable object and that's it ;)